# clearInterval isn't working (have followed the steps in the other questions)

Tags: javascript, android, react-native, setinterval, clearinterval

I know this question is fairly common, and I've followed the solutions listed there and have had no success with them which is why I've made a new question.

I am attempting to create a time/ clock on React Native (if someone has a library that can do that, that would also be appreciated) and currently am creating it like this:

```
  const [time, setTime] = useState(moment(new Date()).format('hh:mm A (DD/MM/YYYY)'));

  function TimeView() {
    setTime(moment(new Date()).format('hh:mm A (DD/MM/YYYY)'));
  }

  const timeVar = setInterval(TimeView, 60000);
```

I have tried const, var, let for timeVar, and no success

And have the timer switch off when the user moves to the next screen like so:

```
  <Button
      onPress={{   
        // navigation code here
            clearInterval(timeVar);
          }}
        >
          Take
 </Button>
```

I'm not sure what I'm doing wrong here, and any help will be appreciated. Thanks!

**Edit:** from Uğur Eren's suggestions, I instead defined this function, however the timer does not work via this method.

```
function Interval(fn, time) {
  const timer = useRef();

  this.start = function () {
    if (!this.isRunning()) {
      timer.current = setInterval(fn, time);
    }
  };

  this.stop = function () {
    clearInterval(timer);
    timer.current = false;
  };

  this.isRunning = function () {
    return timer !== false;
  };
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In case you've stumbled here in search for an answer, I hope this one helps (worked for me).

First created the timer useState variable, along with the function to be run:

```
 const [time, setTime] = useState(moment(new Date()).format('hh:mm A (DD/MM/YYYY)'));


 function TimeView() {
    setTime(moment(new Date()).format('hh:mm A (DD/MM/YYYY)'));
  }

 const timeVar = useRef();
```

Next, setup a useEffect hook to start your interval when the page is loaded for the first time:

```
  useEffect(() => {
    if (isFocused) {
      timeVar.current = setInterval(TimeView, 60000);
    }
  }, []);
```

And put your clearInterval in your button as so:

```
<Button onPress={()=>clearInterval(timeVar.current)} title="Stop" />
```

And that's it, your timer is all set up!

Answer (score 0):

Try this one. You should use setInterval when the component mounts.

```
 const [time, setTime] = useState(moment(new Date()).format('hh:mm A (DD/MM/YYYY)'));
 const [timeVar, setTimeVar] = useState<any>();

 useEffect(() => {
  const interval = setInterval(() => {
    setTime(moment(new Date()).format('hh:mm A (DD/MM/YYYY)'));
  }, 60000);
  setTimeVar(interval);
 }, []);
```

For the button, you have to pass a function to clear timeVar.

```
<Button
      onPress={() => {   
        // navigation code here
            if(timeVar) {
              clearInterval(timeVar);
            }
          }}
        >
          Take
 </Button>
```

Comment: Tried your solution, but unfortunately no success. I console logged timevar and when I press the button, it shows a different id. Not sure what's happening there.